# Ionic 5 Modal UI not binding to controller properties

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I have a modal with an input and setting the input in the controller with a default value.
The input does not show the default value and when entering a value into the input, it does not apply to the controller property.

Modal Input:

[image]

Modal Controller:

[image]

Binding not working:

[image]

Any idea why the binding is not working on the modal?

Comment: try binding to the value property instead of ngmodel

Comment: @rdr20 using `value` will load die default value, but won't apply 2 way binding, so changing the input won't reflect in controller

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after a few hours.

I had to `import` the modal's `Module` into the parent's `Module`.